# pyftpdlib Networkprotocol Error

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, ftp, ipv6

I am using pyftpdlib and pymongo to build a FTP server with GridFS.
Locally everything is working great.

Now I want to run the server using Docker. I am using the Dockerimage python:3.6-alpine and a mongo:latest image.

I run the ftp with:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 21:21 ftpimage
```

And the mongo image with:

```
docker run -it --rm mongo
```

Then I connect with:

```
ftp localhost
```

Login is working and `pwd` comand aswell. But when I run `ls` I get the following error:

```
522 Network protocol not supported (use 1).
500 Command "LPRT" not understood.
ftp: bind: Address already in use
```

I was looking through the RFCs and `use 1` means IPv4. But I don't use anything else.
The FTP-Server doesn't list any erorrs. Just my ftp client. And I don't know why it uses IPv6.

When I enter `sudo netstat -lptu` I get this:

```
tcp6  0  0 [::]:ftp  [::]:*  LISTEN  4972/docker-proxy
```

Can anybody tell me where this comes from? I haven't setup any IPv6 stuff.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Try launching your ftp container with `docker run --net=host...` you need access to the net structures of the host

Comment: Show us verbose `ftp` log (`ftp -v`)